# Primary endpoint not showing on Azure Storage static website

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm setting up static website on my Azure Storage by following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal).

I was able to set it up and upload my files but the `Primary Endpoint` is not showing under `Static Website` -- see below. Any idea why?

[image]

P.S. I'm able to access the website using the full blob URL i.e. `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$web/index.html` but there should be an endpoint that is a bit more user friendly which doesn't include `$web` in it and I don't have to type `index.html` for the static web pages to come up.

Comment: Can you share the `kind`, `tier`, `location` of the storage account?

Comment: Account Kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2), Peformance/Access Tier: Standard/Hot and Location: West US

Comment: can you share what you see in `status`, `replication` on overview section of storage account? I'm trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: try this url - `https://myaccount.z22.web.core.windows.net/`.

Comment: Status: Primary: Available and Replication: Locally-redundant storage (LRS). In case it's important, my storage account was v1 and about an hour ago, I upgraded it to v2.

Comment: The URL you suggested didn't bring up the website.

Comment: I reproduced your issue. I could see the URLs just after refreshing the page. I think after upgrading from V1 to V2 something related to this is not synced in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue. It happens when a storage account is migrated from V1 to V2.

The fix for this is to Refresh the page or navigate away and come back to the storage account. Then you should see the URLs.

you can also get the url using Azure CLI

`az storage account show --name myaccount --query 'primaryEndpoints.web'`

Comment: I tried both to no avail. I tried refreshing the page which didn't work. I then closed the browser and even cleared my cache. I still don't see the static website endpoint under `Properties` or `Static Website`. Very strange!

Comment: sad. I guess try logout and login and incognito. It is definitely some syncing issue on your browser.

Comment: I guess I'll give it a bit more time and maybe even try restarting my laptop. Let's see what happens. I do appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Yesterday I opened a ticket to see what was going on. This morning I could see the primary endpoint for the `$web` container. According to the tech support person, the reason why it took so long for me to see the primary endpoint is that because I have close to 100GB of blobs in my storage account, it took 24 hours to convert my storage account from `v1` to `v2`. Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: I had this issue in Visual Studio Code, and restarting it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

so, in your "Properties" blade you don't see "Static website" section?
Update:
[image]

Update 2:
You can get the PRIMARY STATIC WEBSITE ENDPOINT details using Az module with the below command or snippet.

```
(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCEGROUPNAME> -Name <STORAGEACCOUNTNAME>|select PrimaryEndpoints).PrimaryEndpoints.Web
```

Comment: I do see "Static Website". The image I posted in the original post is what I see when I click it. Basically, the `Primary Endpoint` info is missing.

Comment: I've attached a snapshot to guide you to the settings

Comment: Still not working! I refreshed the page, navigated away and came back. Even cleared browser cache but still not showing up.

Comment: This seems a bug, you can submit a support ticket, or use the AZ module (see update #2) or if possible create a v2 from scratch.